# How can I force users to receive all services in the IBM Maximo receiving application?

Tags: maximo

I need to find an implementation method for the following situation: In the Reception application in Maximo I need to force users to receive all services scheduled in Workorder. How could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

I tried to create a button in the dialog window that, by pressing it, would receive all services automatically. On this button I set the toggleselectrow event but when I press it only one service line is received, not all of them as I would need.